# chrome not storing token in local storage in my vue js application

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome

i'm trying to store token in my local storage but google chrome doesn't store the token even after getting a successful response from my backend

this is my template

```
<br>EMAIL:
    <input type="text" v-model="email">
    <br>PASSWORD:
    <input type="password" v-model="password">
    <br>
    <button @click="submit">signup</button>
```

this is my script tag, if there's token is should go to the "/" but it keeps redirecting me back to login

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  data: () => ({
    email: "",
    password: ""
  }),
  methods: {
    async submit() {
      return axios({
        method: "post",
        data: {
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password
        },
        url: "http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
      })
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res);
          this.$router.push({ path: "/" });
        })
        .catch(error => {
          const message = error.response.data.message;
        });
    },
    clear() {
      this.$refs.form.reset();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

this is the response i get in my console

```
{
    "success": true,
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.KaSGPy3arsd5N5Ef-yDgUWV2zpYzuZ16YT1Hqe19eec"
}
```

even with the token i get if i check my application tab in my dev tools i dont see any token, which means i can't access any of my route please how can i go about this, tried downgrading chrome but still same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not storing the token in the browser that's why.... in your .then function add

```
 localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want store token to local storage

```
....
.then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      localStorage.setItem('token', res.token) // you need add this line
      this.$router.push({ path: "/" });
...
```

Answer (score 1):

there is nothing in your code that would suggest that the token is actually saved anywhere. you're just logging out the response data.

```
localStorage.setItem('token', res.token)
```

and when you wish to use that token

```
let token = localStorage.getItem('token')
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, in the code you've provided you aren't setting any values into the Local Storage as you've claimed.

To set your token into Local Storage, use this in then `then()` block:

```
localStorage.setItem('token', res.token);
```

Secondly, you haven't added any conditionals to check if a token exists and to redirect to a page based on it, as you've claimed.

Depending on your need, add an `if` condition and check if the token exists in the Local Storage (and maybe if its valid too), and then specify the redirection.

```
if (localStorage.getItem('token') && isTokenValid()) {
    this.$router.push({ path: "/" });
} else {
    this.$router.push({ path: "/login" });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
res.cookie("jwtoken", token, {
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + 25892000000),
        httpOnly: true,
      });
```

use this code to store token after generating token in login backend part